# show results from extractall function in one column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column to my data frame with a list of numbers in another column. In column "street" I've got not only the name of the street but sometimes also the number of building and flat. I want to add the column and check which rows contain numbers and what specific numbers are they.

I've got one column in data frame like this:

```
street_name
===========
Maine 70 , 50
Oak 2/52
Seventh 2
Sixth
```

Now my code is:

```
street_df=pd.read_csv('street.csv',encoding='windows-1250',error_bad_lines=False,delimiter=';')
street_df['street_rep']=street_df.iloc[:,0].str.replace(',','/')
street_df['street_rep1']=street_df.iloc[:,1].str.replace('/','')
street_df['street_num']=street_df.iloc[:,2].str.extractall('(\d+)').astype(str).unstack().apply(','.join)
```

Now my output is:

**TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index (0, 1)')**

and I would like to receive one column like this:

```
all_numbers:
============
70,50
2,52
2
```

with all numbers which has occured in column `street_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex` for this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'street': ['Maine 70 , 50','Oak 2/52','Seventh 2','Sixth']})

def find_num(x):
    j = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', x)
    return ",".join(j)

df['all numbers'] = df['street'].apply(find_num)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          street      all numbers                                                                                                                   
0  Maine 70 , 50       70,50                                                                                                                   
1       Oak 2/52        2,52                                                                                                                   
2      Seventh 2           2                                                                                                                   
3          Sixth
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.find_all`:

```
In [11]: df.street_address.str.findall('\d+')
Out[11]:
0    [70, 50]
1     [2, 52]
2         [2]
3          []
Name: street_address, dtype: object
```

and if you need this as a comma separated string, chain `str.join`:

```
In [12]: df.street_address.str.findall('\d+').str.join(',')
Out[12]:
0    70,50
1     2,52
2        2
3
Name: street_address, dtype: object
```